# How to deal with the situation that the parent branch was merged to develop before a child branch?

Tags: git, git-merge

My coworker created the feature-parent-branch 20 days ago and I created the feature-child-branch 15 days ago using `git town`. Then he merged the feature-parent-branch to the develop branch 12 days ago. Then I finished my ticket 2 days ago and I merged the feature-child-branch to the feature-parent-branch using `git town`.

However, I found that there are about 50 files differences between feature-parent-branch and develop.

When I worked on the ticket, the main branch was feature-parent-branch in git town config.

I am not sure whether these 50 files are not changed by the recent PRs.
Is there a safe way to merge my code to develop from feature-parent-branch?

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you're referring to https://www.git-town.com/ you should probably mention this in the question. (If you're referring to something different with the same name, well, I'll let you provide the link.)

Answer (score 0):

Now, I got the ways to solve this kind of problem if creating a feature-child-branch based on a feature-parent-branch while feature-parent-branch was merged to develop earlier than feature-child-branch:

1. reset the git-town config to develop.
2. sync develop to feature-child-branch and solve conflicts.
3. ship feature-child-branch.